# ubuntu for samsung galaxy s6

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung, phone

Is there a version available for the Samsung Galaxy S6?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no port of Ubuntu Touch for the Samsung Galaxy S6.

Refer on the [Ubuntu Touch Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) for more information and to see an updated list of supported devices.